# Managing error state for multiple related Fields

Tags: react-final-form

I wonder what the equivalent is to the `redux-form` `Fields` tag in `React-Final-Form`?

I need to process errors for a number of related fields in a single component in order to show when an error state for a common label if one of the sub fields has an error.

I guess it's not entirely obvious to me how to implement this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

[Here's your answer](https://codesandbox.io/s/pyrwplknom). Just added it to the docs. You're not the first to ask this question, but you're the straw that made me break down and actually write it. So thanks for that!